# Call constructor within constructor with self(this)-parameter

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, this

I need to link an object of type B to any instance of type A (circular dependencies). I could also declare another method, which must be called after the constructor of A and link a new B to an A-instance. What I want to achieve is not having to call such a method manually. This is the sample code:

```
public Class A{
    B b;
    public A(){
        b = new B(this); // this does not work,
                         // as this references an object that has not been created yet
    }
}

public Class B{
    A a;
    public B(A a){
        this.a = a; //or something else
    }
}
```

I commented the problematic line. I also understand why it can't work. What I need to know is, if there is a well-known design pattern to avoid this problematic? Or should I just redesign my class model, putting anything in B to A? Any suggestions?

Comment: you must study dependency injection principle which is the core of spring framework,and which is there to resolve these types of problems

Comment: What are you specifically trying to make? Given the project details might influence different answers.

Comment: You may just have to use set methods instead.  I'm not sure how you would do this in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

It *does* work. It's problematic in that it exposes an object before it's been fully initialized (so if the `B` constructor calls methods on the parameter, for example, that could be a bad thing), but it does *work*. The reference `B.a` will be a reference to the instance of `A` that's been/being constructed.

I would recommend trying to avoid the cyclic reference where possible, but where the alternative is even worse, the code you've given will work.

Comment: can't we consider using Dependency injection in this case?

Comment: @Algorithmist: Well if the two fields are actually `final`, dependency injection doesn't really help much - the only way to get two final fields in objects which refer to each other is to use something like this. We don't really have enough context here to comment on alternatives.

Comment: @JonSkeet Class A is a graph class. There are data structures and method to handle a graph (add and remove edges, and so on). Class B is a degree sequence class, with some methods to calculate degree sequences, adjust them and so on. In my model, every graph object should have one degree sequence object, where the graph itself should be final. I don't know how dependency object is going to work, as the degree sequence can first be calculated when the graph is build, and the degree sequence should be built after the graph is created.

Comment: @user2653076: Well if the fields are non-final, you *could* just set one of them after both objects have been constructed - but if you want the cyclic dependency, it should be okay so long as you're careful in the constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Using this approach is not recommended and possibly create runtime exception because the object is not fully initialized. We can take simple scenario as:

```
public class A {
    B b;
    String s;
    public A(){
        b = new B(this); // this does not work, as this references an object that has not been created yet
        s = "print me";
    }
}


public class B {
    A a;
    public B(A a){
        this.a = a; //or something else
        System.out.println(this.a.s); // will same as a.s;
    }
}
```

It will output `null` because a partially initialized reference is copied to constructor. This code compiles because compiler doesn't find anything missing in code as all appropriate references and variable are there.